# creating a .csv table for image statistics using loop in GEE

Tags: javascript, for-loop, export-to-csv, google-earth-engine

I have calculated the *mean , mode, median* of all bands of an image.

Now I want to display the result as a table in `.csv`, as shown in example output:
[image: table I want as result]

I tried following code, which is also on [Google's Cloud IDE, Earth Engine (EE) Code Editor](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9a51eae7306fc7695f58b0638e9f1cc2):

```
// Extract the bands from collection and make a list
var bands= ee.List([
                    [ 'B1','0.45','0.092377477','0.086616925','0.086616925'],
                     ['B2','0.51','0.085137095','0.076246974','0.076246974'],
                     ['B3','0.59','0.062736553','0.053236987','0.044920224'],
                     ['B4','0.67','0.324248892','0.334150672','0.357299032'],
                     ['B5','0.88','0.161820343','0.157588621','0.153408903'],
                     ['B6','1.65','0.3812067','0.295290527','293.7689209'],
                     ['B7','2.29','0.076728936','0.064302692','0.052958585'],
                     ['B8','0.5','672.0124447','671','672']]);

var featList=bands.map(function(list){
  return ee.Feature(null).set({bands:ee.List(list).get(0),wavelength:ee.List(list).get(1),
      mean:ee.List(list).get(2),median:ee.List(list).get(3),mode:ee.List(list).get(4)})
})
var features = ee.FeatureCollection(featList)
print(features)
```

I am told to display the result using a **for loop**.
I cannot understand how to use the loop here.

Comment: What you want to display(data)?

Comment: Please add the array also.

Comment: I have added the image description of what I want to display and how.Please have a look.